# AWS EC2 Ubuntu16.04 crontab not working at specified time

Tags: amazon-web-services, shell, amazon-ec2, cron, cron-task

As titled, i have read through a lot different online resources, but still not be able to make crontab work at specified time, it only works when the the job is specified for every minute.

p.s I have changed the timezone to Asia/Hong_Kong via `dpkg-reconfigure tzdata`, Also

```
$TZ=Asia/Hong_Kong
```

I have tried

1. Added `PATH=$PATH` in crontab from `crontab -e`
2. Added `SHELL=/bin/sh` in crontab from `crontab -e`
3. Use full path
4. Tri to do 1-3 in sudo nano /etc/crontab
5. Restart cron via sudo service cron restart

my job:

`54 22 * * * /bin/sh /home/ubuntu/F/start.sh`

Also tried,

```
* * * * * date > /home/ubuntu/log_cron.txt
```

and in `log_cron.txt`
It displayed: Sun Apr 21 23:02:01 HKT 2019

Any ideas how to get cron job work in AWS EC2, with specified timezone and at specified time?

Answer (score 0):

From `man -S8 cron`:

> **ENVIRONMENT**
>
> If configured in /etc/default/cron in Debian systems, the cron daemon localisation settings environment can be managed through the use of /etc/environment or through the use of /etc/default/locale with values from the latter overriding values from  the  former. These  files  are  read  and  they will be used to setup the LANG, LC_ALL, and LC_CTYPE environment variables. These variables are then used to set the charset of mails, which defaults to 'C'.
>
> This does NOT affect the environment of tasks running under cron. For more information on how to modify the environment of tasks, consult crontab(5)
>
> > ***The daemon will use, if present, the definition from /etc/timezone for the timezone.***
>
> The environment can be redefined in user's crontab definitions but cron will only  handle tasks in a single timezone.

I believe that the timezone has to be set prior to instantiating the cron daemon.

In case you are asking about CloudWatch service on AWS and not the one on your vm... in this case, everything is scheduled in UTC time:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/scheduled_tasks.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/ScheduledEvents.html